# PHP or jQuery arrays problem

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
$('[name=rescheck[]]:checked').each(function(){
        room_id.push($(this).val());
    });

<input type="checkbox" name="rescheck[]" value="<?php echo $roomid; ?>" />
```

Which submits checked checkboxes which contains ids(room_id) to a PHP script. When I alert the room_id in javascript it displays ids like these 1,2,3,4 - is this how arrays in Javascript suppose to be? thats my first question.

next is my php:

```
$c_array=$_POST['cvalue'];      
    echo $c_array;

    foreach(c_array as $ch)
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation VALUES('','$prop_id','$ch','$name_r','$contact_r','$email_r','')");
    }
```

If my Javascript above is correct, then the problem is in php, cause I've displayed the PHP result (echo $c_array) through `console.log` in firebug and it only displays the last id.

GUYS, what seems to be the problem here? Is it my Javascript code? or the PHP code?

MY AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "reservation-valid.php",
                    data: {name_r:name_r, email_r:email_r,contact_r:contact_r,prop_id:p_id,cvalue:room_id},
                    success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    //alert("Reservation submitted for APPROVAL.");


                    }
                }); 

            });
```

Comment: Please post more of your code. Are you submitting the form with a regular get/post or with ajax? Either way you shouldn't _need_ to preprocess the form as you're doing now.

Comment: What's the generated HTML look like? one input field with `value="1,2,3,4"`, or one input field with `value="1"`, a second with `value="2"`, etc...?

Comment: Please use the function `var_dump();` for returning variables values instead of `echo();`, it gives more (helpfull) information.

Comment: im using ajax post. i have no form in my html. just .click event in jquery to submit my selected checkboxes.

Comment: @marc B: what you mean by html generated? i alerted it using javascript alert(); so it gives me 1,2,3,4 display.

Comment: @user628961: you're building some HTML dynamically to insert those values into the checkbox field - so what's that HTML look like when you look at the page source?

Comment: Where do you populate "cvalue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name="rescheck[]"` will be submitted as an array automatically, that's the reason for the `[]` after the name.  You do not need to "convert" these checkboxes into an array, or do any processing on them.

In PHP, you could then use: `$c_array = $_POST['rescheck'];`, and this will be an array of the checked boxes.

**EDIT:**  Try this:

```
var postData = {
  name_r: name_r,
  email_r: email_r,
  contact_r: contact_r,
  prop_id: p_id
};
var postDataStr = $.param(postData)+'&'+$('[name="rescheck[]"]').serialize();

$.ajax({
  data: postDataStr
  dataType: 'json' //<-- this will make jQuery parse JSON for you
  ...
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data.success);
    alert(data.message);
  }
});
```

In PHP:

```
$c_array = $_POST['cvalue'];  
....
$return = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Data saved');
echo json_encode($return);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: i see your point. but take note that i am not using form in my checkbox HTML. is it ok? can i still pass the rescheck[] array normall through .click event in jquery?

Comment: @user628961: You really should put the checkboxes inside `<form>` tags.  Then, when you submit it, you can use `$('form').serialize()` to get the data.

Comment: but when i try to enclose my html with form.  the div and tables will break their position.

Comment: @user628961: `$('[name="rescheck[]"]').serialize()` will give you a query string, but you'd have to convert your other data to query strings also, using `$.param()`.  See edited answer.

Comment: @rocket: believe me, ive tried that. i even tried that with .replace(%5b%D,[]) - not sure with the content thought cause i deleted that code already in my page cause it still doesnt work with it.

Comment: @user628961: Try what I added to my answer.

Comment: then how would my php looks like? how would i loop the array to insert all ids i fetched from checkboxes to database? im currently using foreach($c_array as $ch) and it gives me an invalid argument for foreach func error in firebug.

Comment: man. i tried your code. i alert the postDataStr and it displays this - name_r=das&email_r=dsa&contact_r=dasdsa&prop_id=1&rescheck%5B%5D=1&rescheck%5B%5D=2&rescheck%5B%5D=6&rescheck%5B%5D=7

Comment: @user628961: `postDataStr` is correct.  Use that as the data parameter in `$.ajax`.  Then in PHP, `$c_array = $_POST['rescheck']` should work.

Comment: yeah. it actually worked. hahahaha. rocket your like a programming God. thanks. can i make a follow-up question? its not related to this post but still in jquery. too tired to post another question.

Comment: that checkboxes im asking is for reservation. that room_id is the ids of rooms checked. so i want to limit the reservations of 20 reservations per day, is it possible? my php side doesnt have a UI so i cant make an alert or echo that reservations has reached it limit. im only counting on the success return, and i dont know what to put there to alert something that came from my php. hope you get what i mean

Comment: @user628961: You can use JavaScript to check `$('[name="rescheck[]"]').length` before.  You can also have PHP return JSON data, so you can have it return a message.  See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that your $_POST is referring to room_id, however your html element has the form field being rescheck[].  Are you submitting the form via ajax?  If so post that snippet of code as well, because that  would likely be a source of some of your issues.

If you are submitting the form, then there isn't the need for that jquery snippet in terms of just checking off checkboxes and reading them on page  submit.

Comment: yes im submitting it via ajax. room_id in post is typo error. its some other variable. i have no form in my html. i just use .click event in jquery as a trigger to pass the selected checkboxes.

Comment: Then please post your ajax call, because your problem is most likely in that set of code.

Comment: i posted it already. i dont think its in ajax the problem is.

Answer (score -2):

On the PHP side use json_encode ( http://php.net/json_encode ) to encapsulate your arrays and on the Javascript side use jQuery.parseJSON ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ ) to decode the data into an array

Comment: please dont give me json. i dont have time to study plugins anymore. this is urgent. sorry but do you have other solutions? but if its the only way, how do i get json? how to include it in my pages?

Comment: The OP is trying to post an array *to* PHP, not send one from PHP.